# Color Trefoil-Knot

Tags: graphics, curated-data, knots

i need some help to plot a three colored Trefoil knot. 
I found on Wolfram the code

`Graphics[Transpose[{{Red,Blue,Green,Red},KnotData["Trefoil","KnotDiagramData"]}]]`

for the three colored Trefoil but i want the line segments thicker.

Can someone help me please and maybe give a another example for a 3-color Knot?

Comment: Try using `Directive[Thickness[.05], #] & /@ {Red, Blue, Green, Red}` instead of `{Red, Blue, Green, Red}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pack all of that styling into a `Directive`.

For a general function that'll work no matter what styling choices, you can try this:

```
With[{
  d = KnotData["FigureEight", "KnotDiagramData"],
  individualStyles = {Red, Blue, Green, Pink},
  commonStyles = Thickness[.05]
  },
 Graphics[
  Transpose[{
    Directive @@ Flatten[{commonStyles, #}] & /@

     Take[Flatten@ConstantArray[individualStyles, Length@d], Length@d],
    d
    }]]
 ]
```

[image: asd]

Just tweak the stuff in the `With` variable declarations